# How to convert Android Uri to Java URI

Tags: android, uri

I'm trying to figure out how to convert an Android Uri to a Java URI.  What I'm trying to do is get a File, but as far as I can tell, I need to pass it a Java URI.

Here's my Uri that I'm attempting to convert:

```
content://media/external/images/media/100
```

And what I'm attempting to get at:

```
File mediaFile = new File(new URI("android.net.Uri"));
```

Where "android.net.Uri" is my Uri object

If there is a different/better way to get a java.io.File object from this content Uri, I'm open to suggestions as I've searched far and wide with no luck so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it figured out, I was able to get the real filepath of the Uri and then create the File:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/47");

String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cur = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
cur.moveToFirst();
String path = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

mediaFile = new File(path);
```

Comment: Can you check the green checkbox so this is marked as Answered?

Comment: I will, however I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer :)

Comment: since managedQuery is deprecated now, people can use the following instead: getContentResolver().query(uri, ...)